# Group by first two characters of column, in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

I'm using Tableau Desktop v9.0. I have data that looks like this:

```
code,items
02050252,7
03040620,19
03060423,3
```

I want to create a bar chart of the items grouped by the first two characters of the `code` field.

So effectively a chart that shows this underlying data:

```
new_code,items
02,7
03,22
```

Is it possible to do this within Tableau? Or do I need to group the data manually myself first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can definitely do this within Tableau.

Make sure that your code column is a string. If it's not, right click on it in the dimensions section and choose `Change Data Type`.

Then, create a calculated field (Analysis -> Create Calculated Field) and enter the expression `LEFT([Code], 2)`, which will take the first two characters of the code field.

[image: Create a custom field]

Drag your `new_code` field to the Rows shelf and `Items` to the Columns shelf and voila, you have your desired data. You can of course change the type of the chart, make it a table, etc. from here.

[image: Completed chart]